ConversationBlockedByUser","message":"User blocked the conversation with the bot
I face an unexplainable issue today where the user side approval received an error as below:

Request to the Bot framework failed with error:
'{"error":{"code":"ConversationBlockedByUser","message":"User blocked
the conversation with the bot."}}'.

But the problem is, the user never block the Workflow chat and it is his first time to approve the request so I'm kinda out of idea how to fix this. Is anyone out there that face the same issue? Is there any fix?

I found no answer at any site so I go with my thought and method instead to solve this issue.

The user did not receive any approval from Workflow chat at all. So I get to user to go to his Microsoft Teams -> Apps -> Type Workflows in search bar -> add/open (any applicable)

After that, click Chat -> get the user to type Learn More in Workflows chat -> wait for the reply/response from the Workflows. Once the user receive the response, trigger the flow.


After trying the above method, the user are now able to receive the approval from Workflow chat.
